# Send data via curl from page a to page b and load page b via iframe on page a

Tags: php, curl, iframe

I have 2 pages a.php and b.php. I am sending few data from page a.php to the page b.php.
After that i am trying to load page b.php via iframe at page a.php.

Page a.php code is below:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/test/b.php';

$post = array('var1'=>'abc','var2'=>'def');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);

?>
<iframe src="http://localhost/test/b.php"></iframe>

<?php die; ?>
```

Page b.php code is below:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1']; ?>">

<?php die; ?>
```

If I print_r($_POST); at b.php then i can see post data is coming there, but when I am using the data in a HTML text box and trying to load the page b.php via iframe. It's saying 
**Notice**:  Undefined index: var1 in **/var/www/html/test/b.php** on line **4**

Can you please check and suggest what I am doing mistake here OR if there are any other way please suggest.

in b.php I Tried below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://localhost/test/b.php">
<input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1']; ?>">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

After that in a.php echo $result; It's showing many iframe one on another and i can not see textbox, please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/naZND.png.

Comment: The `$result` of your `curl_exec()` contains the result of the loading of page b. You don't need to load page b again in an iframe, you can just use `echo $result;`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  in b.php  I Tried below  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://localhost/test/b.php">
<input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1']; ?>">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>  After that in a.php echo $result;    It's showing many iframe one on another and i can not see textbox.

Comment: You don't need to use an iframe anywhere. Page a loads page b using a cURL session. Therefore using `echo $result;` is enough to render page b from within page a.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware iframe is required, I can see HTML <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1']; ?>"> in $result  when I am using only <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1']; ?>">  in the b.php, but we need an ifame.